# HBase: Difference between Regionserver and QuorumPeer

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to Hbase. Now I have a simple question : what's the difference between regionserver and quorumpeer. Regionservers list is in the file regionserver and quorumpeer should be configured in HBase_site.xml. I guessed regions of a Hbase table can only be stored in region servers but I have no idea with quorumpeer. Should any node of hbase cluser be regionserver and quorumpeer at the same time? If you know, please explain to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For hBase to work it needs Zookeeper so that the regionServers and Hmaster can communicate and transfer data. CHeck this out http://hbase.apache.org/book/zookeeper.html
You need to have a quorum of Zookeeper servers running (generally 3 or 5) 
You have to list the nodes where  Zk servers are running in the hbase.zookeeper.quorum  property in HBase-site.xml